# Trouble compiling program with Android shared object

Tags: linux, gcc, java-native-interface, arm

I am trying to write a simple HelloWorld program to run on Android using the Sourcery Codebench ARM cross-compiler.

Initially I was having issues running my executable on Android as it was compiled as a dynamically linked executable as seen below:
    hello1:    ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV),     dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.7.0,     BuildID[sha1]=3e1cddb8843bcaf8a1eb9777b4ebfdeb75d35501, not stripped

After adding -static I was able to run it as a statically linked program and it was able to run.

However this is not enough, what I eventually would like to do is be able to compile the program as dynamically linked executable and link it to a shared object library as found within /system/lib on the Android device.

I tried to do this with the simple HelloWorld program which requires the libc library.  I pulled the libc.so file from Android and tried to link however I get the following error:
/usr/local/share/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/peyman/Security/H715BL/libc.so when searching for -lc

I am not sure which .so library it is seeking so I performed readelf -d on an executable and found the following:
readelf -d hello1

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x678 contains 24 entries:
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x4003b0
0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x400628
0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x410660
0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
...
```

I was not able to find libc.so.6 on the Android device and I'm not sure where I can retrieve this from, however it has me stuck here.

I do know that through my research, utilizing NDK for native development was the key, however I'd rather not venture there at this moment unless it's absolutely necessary.

If anyone can steer me in the right direction, I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Android is not GNU/Linux; Bionic is not Glibc. Allow me to paraphrase _"I'd rather not [stop using the wrong toolchain and use an appropriate one] at this moment unless it's absolutely necessary"_...

Comment: I was able to properly compile a shared object executable and execute it on Android without utilizing NDK.  Thanks for your answer though :)